# Ember where is this.get() looking?

Tags: ember.js, calendar

I've been looking through all of the code of [ember-power-calendar](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-calendar) and I am trying to change the `selected` value to have another item in its object.

[On this line](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-calendar/blob/master/addon/components/power-calendar.js#L60), it's calling for `selected: this.get('selected'),` but I can't seem to find where it's getting `'selected'` from.  Is it looking outside of its own file?  The imports aren't very descriptive, but I have a feeling it's in one of them:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import { guidFor } from '@ember/object/internals';
import { inject } from '@ember/service';
import moment from 'moment';
import { task } from 'ember-concurrency';
import layout from '../templates/components/power-calendar';
```

No where else in the file has a method called `selected`, so I'm wondering where it's getting this value from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the component, we need to pass the `selected` property to that component, this is where it comes from.

```
{{#power-calendar selected=arrival onSelect=(action (mut arrival) value="moment") as |calendar|}}
  {{calendar.nav}}
  {{calendar.days}}
{{/power-calendar}}
```

Comment: Aaah, so it's getting the "selected" value from the `selected=arrival` on the calendar itself and if it's blank, it's null to begin with

Comment: Yes. We will always provide `selected` property, that's how we can get the selected value